# Creating Dynamic variables from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JSON response looks like this :

```
{"sample":[{"id":"2","name":"branch name"},{"id":"3","name":"branch name 2"}]}
```

My function looks like this :

```
function getJSONObjects(){
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/api/branches",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.sample, function(i,item){
           var loc = "branch";
           eval("var " + loc + item.id + "=123;");
           alert(loc + item.id);
          });
        });
 }
```

The idea is to create `branch + id` object so I can do something with it(create marker on a map), so I tried to assign it any value to see if this was working.

I wanted both `branch2` and `branch3` to alert `123` so I have something to start with. But currently this alerts branch2 and branch3 instead of 123.

I have little experience with creating dynamic variables/objects can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe another approach towards solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what you want to do here:

```
eval("var " + loc + item.id + "=123;"); // eval is EVIL
alert(loc + item.id); // just creates a string...
```

Creating `dynamic variables` is a bad idea. Rather create an `object` and use key/values.

```
var branches = {}; // new object, move this to the scope you want to access the value from later
branch[item.id] = 123; // set the key 'item.id' to the value '123'
console.log(branch[item.id]); // retrieve the value of the key 'item.id'
```

But if you're doing this you can just as well change the structure of your JSON data to something like this:

```
{"sample":[{"1": {"name": "branch name1", "value": 123}, "2": {"name": "branch name2", "value": 456}}]}
```

Then just grab the elements of the array and use them like `branches` above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function to iterate `data.sample`:

```
function(i,item){
       window[loc + item.id] = 123;
       alert(window[loc + item.id]);
}
```

The `window` object here is used to set a global variable, "dynamically" named on runtime. (This is not a good practice, though.)

If `loc = 'branch'` and `item.id = 2`, the `alert(window[loc + item.id])` statement would be equivalent to `alert(branch2)`.